# Are quoted dictionary keys an absolute must?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Just curious, made an interesting observation that I got away with defining my dictionary keys without having to quote them. I guess this is a vulnerability in Python?

Within a sample, and not in REPL, the following does not raise an exception:

```
>>> {foo:'foo', bar:'bar'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

How do Pythonistas handle their keys? Do you advocate unquoted or quoted keys, and why?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: are you referring to `dict(key=1)` and `{'key':1}`?

Comment: yes, like the above, except `{key:1}` where `key` is not a pre-existing variable. "Got away" because in REPL this throws exception.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A dictionary's keys can be any [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) object (a string, an integer, a tuple, etc.):

```
>>> dct = {'a': 1, 1: 'a'}
>>> dct['a']
1
>>> dct[1]
'a'
>>>
```

Quoting a key simply means that the key is a string, as with `'a'` above.

---

As far as your claim that:

> I got away with defining my keys without having to quote them

I assume that you mean you did something like this:

```
dct = {key1: 1, key2: 'a'}
```

There is really nothing special about the code above.  It just means that the names `key1` and `key2` refer to hashable objects, which now become the keys of the dictionary. An example is below:

```
>>> key1 = 'a'
>>> key2 = 1
>>> dct = {key1: 1, key2: 'a'}
>>> dct[key1]
1
>>> dct[key2]
'a'
>>> dct['a']
1
>>> dct[1]
'a'
>>>
```

---

On the other hand, if you mean that you used the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) built-in to make a dictionary:

```
dct = dict(key1='a', key2=1)
```

Then you should know that the keys are *still normal strings*:

```
>>> dct = dict(key1='a', key2=1)
>>> dct
{'key2': 1, 'key1': 'a'}
>>> dct[key1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'key1' is not defined
>>> dct['key1']
'a'
>>>
```

---

Finally, regarding your question of whether or not you should always use string keys, the answer is *it depends*.  If you need your keys to hold data that can only be represented as a string (such as a person's name), use strings.  If you need the keys to hold numerical data (such as id numbers), use integers or floats or whatever is appropriate.

Simply put, do whatever makes the most sense for your program.

Comment: I think rpattiso may be right, and he may be thinking of constructor syntax: `dict(key1=1, key2='a')`, which means the same thing as `{'key1': 1, 'key2': 'a'}`. Then again, maybe not; it's not easy to tell from the question…

Comment: yes, sorry for the ambiguity. was mostly something like `{foo:'foo', bar:'bar'}`

Comment: @iCodez i had to read it twice, but yeah, it did answer my question!

Comment: actually @iCodez, the question was that the keys were not variables. i'll update the question now.

Comment: @aug2uag - The exception is being thrown because the name `foo` is not defined.  You need to define it before using it, something like `foo = 'whatever'`.

Comment: @iCodez understood, however, "believe it or not", the exception is not thrown outside the REPL (using 2.7). I take it from the discussion, however, that absolutely, the notion not to quote keys is absurd to Pythonistas, and indeed, that was the answer I was looking for. Thanks for your help!