# Sympy solve returns strange dictionary, when it should not return any

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sympy

This question could be related to:

[Python Sympy solve returns list vs. dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957880/python-sympy-solve-returns-list-vs-dictionary)

or

[Are quoted dictionary keys an absolute must?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790920/are-quoted-dictionary-keys-an-absolute-must)

I have this Sympy code, in one of my first attempts to SymPy library:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve



class FunZ:
    
    def __init__(self, f):  
  
        self.x, self.y  = sym.symbols('x y')
        
        self.f = parse_expr(f)
        
        # print('f : ', self.f)
        
    def evalu(self, xx, yy):
    
        return float(self.f.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    

    def derX(self, xx, yy):        
        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        
        # print('dx : ', self.dx)
        
        return float(self.dx.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derY(self, xx, yy):
        
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        
        # print('dy :', self.dy)
        
        return float(self.dy.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derXY(self, xx, yy):
        
        return [float(self.derX(xx, yy)), float(self.derY(xx, yy))]
    
    def minim(self):
        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        print('dx : ', self.dx)
        print('dy : ', self.dy)
        
        eq1 = Eq(self.dx ,0)
        
        eq2 = Eq(self.dy ,0)
        
        solu = solve((eq1,eq2), (self.x, self.y), dict = False) #### HERE dict = False
        
        print(solu, type(solu))
        

        
        return solu 
    
funz = FunZ('x**2 + y**2 + 2*y + 2')

dict_min = funz.minim()

print(dict_min, type(dict_min))

for keys in dict_min:
    print('key : ', keys, 'value : ',  dict_min[keys])

print('values :' , dict_min.values())    

# print(dict_min[x]) ###### ---> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

print(dict_min['x']) ####### -----> KeyError: 'x'
```

my output looks like :

```
dx :  2*x
dy :  2*y + 2
{x: 0, y: -1} <class 'dict'>
{x: 0, y: -1} <class 'dict'>
key :  x value :  0
key :  y value :  -1
values : dict_values([0, -1])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File .....", line 88, in <module>
    print(dict_min['x']) ####### -----> KeyError: 'x'

KeyError: 'x'
```

or

```
    print(dict_min[x]) ###### ---> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I can get x, y with `print('values :' , list(dict_min.values()))` ---> `values : [0, -1]`

If I set the flag dict to True in `solu = solve((eq1,eq2), (self.x, self.y), dict = True)`, I get `[{x: 0, y: -1}] <class 'list'>` as a result

Any idea about what is going on? Is it related on how I defined my Funz class? the results seem plausible to me, but this dict stuff is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access via `dict_min[x]` or `dict_min["x"]` because `x` is of type `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol`. The keys of this dict are of type `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol`.

`dict_min[x]` does not work because no `x` variable is defined in your code.

`dict_min["x"]` does not work because here you define `x` as a `string`, but the key named `x` in `dict_min` is of type `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol`.

There is no problem with your class.

However, you can do this:

```
dict_min[funz.x]
```

or:

```
x = funz.x
dict_min[x]
```

So, `dict_min` is not a strange `dict` type from sympy, that's a classic Python `dict` which keys are of type `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol`. The keys are the symbols of your equation. Perhaps it was confusing because your symbols `x` and `y` were defined in your class and via `sym.symbols('x y')`.

If you want to ALWAYS get a `list`:

In `minim`, you should set `dict=True` instead of `False`. By doing this, you will "always get a list of solution mappings" (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).
Yes, the goal of `dict=True` is to ensure that the returned variable will be of type `list` . I agree that could seems a  bit strange.

Some informations about this flag from the source code of solve(): https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/solvers.py#L406

And here is the effect of the flag `is_dict`: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/solvers.py#L1249

As for sympy 1.9.